# Maintain count of logged in users without using DB or file

Tags: php

I have to maintain a count of the number of users that has been logged in. Is there any way in PHP to do it without using database or creating a file to store details ?

No framework used, just simple plain PHP.

Comment: @matiit session is user dependent. Cannot track site metrics

Comment: @matiit wanted to say the same but sessions also use either file- or database-based storage mechanisms ...

Comment: You can't. The only way to store something out of a database is through a session. And those are user-side. A user can not know which(and how many) other users are on your website without connecting to the server. Thus you need a database or something to store a value which the user can pull out.

Comment: If you are free to use `redis`, try this [http://redis.io/commands/incr](http://redis.io/commands/incr)

Comment: @shatheesh - okay. but not using redis

Answer (score 2):

Your options are literally, a data store or a file. You could alternatively offload them to some remote server which does something or find some sort of "remember some data" third party API, but realistically it needs to be a data store or a file.

Files would be kinda slow at this and you would get race conditions, so you'd be right to avoid those.

A MySQL Database or the like is possibly also overkill if you are not currently using one.

Another option (as @shatheesh pointed out) is Redis.

http://redis.io/commands/incr

I would suggest you do that. :)

Comment: Python can read to and from the same data store just as easily yes, as can any other language with a Redis binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a session variable and storing count in same.

For further understanding you can visit this link :

[How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)